dbt source table named group - issue
Running dbt core version 1.6.10 and Snowflake
I have a source table named group.
When I execute dbt run... command I get "...unexpected group." error.
In the source yml file I was setting the following.
 - name: group
  quote: true
Hoping that would allow me to put quotes around the source.
select * from {{ source('my_schema', '"group"') }}
When I execute that I get "...depends on a source named 'my_schema."group" which was not found" error.
Is there a way to make this work with a reserved word, or is renaming that table the only solution?

Hi - why would you use a reserved word as the name for an object? That seems like a really bad idea, especially when choosing any other name is so much simpler than dealing with the impact of trying to use reserved words as object names

Totally agree, in this instance we were able to change the name but if dealing with a 3rd party app it might not be possible so was wondering if using an alias might work, but didn't.

This one worked for me some time ago.
sources.yml
  - name: my_schema
    database: <...>
    schema: <...>
    tables:
      - name: '"GROUP"'

models/model.sql
SELECT * FROM {{ source('my_schema', '"GROUP"') }}

Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.
